# How can I select an option in a drop down box from $_GET in Php

Tags: php, dropdownbox

This question looks similar to others but seems to be unique (to the forums at least).

I have a form on a page in which a user selects an option from a form:

```
<!-- <option value="" onClick="" >Select Country</option>  -->
<option value="38" onClick="" >Canada</option>
<!-- <option value="222" onClick="" >United Kingdom</option> -->
<option value="223" onClick="" >United States</option></select></td>
```

It is passed on to a new form page which is coded identically to the first form. For the other fields in the form I am able to use the following echo but it does not work to select the proper option in the dropdown.

Code to enter user original form data into new form text field:

```
<input type="text" id='fields_city' name='fields_city'  value="<?php echo $_GET['Ship_City']; ?>" />
```

Code to enter user original form data into new form dropdown field:

```
<select border="0"  class="" id="country" style="width:149px;" name="country"  size="1" selected="selected"  value="<?php echo $_GET['Ship_Country']; ?>"
```

I basically just need to prepopulate the dropdown with the user selected item.

Comment: what's the name of your "select"

Comment: you need to look up "Canada" and insert that. The only thing your form will be submitting is "value=38".

Comment: Marc B. If I want to select US why would I select Canada?

Comment: this is the URL output...index.php?CID=18&AFID=1002&SID=&C1=&Ship_First=TEST&Ship_Last=TEST&Ship_Address1=TEST&Ship_City=TEST&e_mail=bmsedina@primlinsssenutra.com&Bill_Phone=3055555555&Ship_Zip=33009&Ship_Country=United%20States&Ship_State=AL

Comment: Select name = Ship_Country

Answer (score 0):

Using `select_name` since you didn't show your select.  Also assuming `get` since that's what you used and didn't show the form.  This echos `selected` if it was on the previous form, therefore selecting that option:

```
<option value="38" onClick="" <?php echo $_GET['select_name'] == 38 ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Canada</option>
```

Comment: not working because the "38" & "223" are not being passed in the url

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php If ($_GET['Ship_Country'] == "38") { echo "selected"; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the new page select box for each option you could do something like this. I believe this should work, unless I misunderstood you.

```
<option value="38" <?= $_GET['Ship_City'] == '38' ? selected : ""; ?>>Canada</option>
<option value="223" <?= $_GET['Ship_City'] == '223' ? selected : ""; ?>>United States</option></select></td>
```

Comment: This is the URL output...index.php?CID=18&AFID=1002&SID=&C1=&Ship_First=TEST&Ship_Last=TEST&Ship‌​_Address1=TEST&Ship_City=TEST&e_mail=bmsedina@primlinsssenutra.com&Bill_Phone=305‌​5555555&Ship_Zip=33009&Ship_Country=United%20States&Ship_State=AL – Its not sending the Value=ID

Comment: <option value="38" <?= $_GET['Ship_Country'] == 'Canada' ? selected : ""; ?>>Canada</option>
<option value="223" <?= $_GET['Ship_Country'] == 'United States' ? selected : ""; ?>>United States</option>